# Loading (sign out) problem

Tags: pokemon-go

Unfortunately I have a new problem. I have got an LTE for my mobile and everything runs ok as long as I log into the app when I am connected on my wifi. However when I try to log in while being on the LTE I get stuck on the loading screen with the sign out button. When I click it, it gets me on screen where you between signing in with your google account and the pokemon trainer account. When I choose google account I get stuck on another loading screen. And when I dont click the sign out button nothing happens aswell. Is there someone who knows what is wrong and how to fix it? Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: I had a simular issue this morning, but it turned out that I was randomly connecting to a weak "Free Wifi" nearby.  While you're outside, try rebooting your phone, turning the wifi off, then seeing if the game makes the connection.  If that works, I'll offer it as an answer.

Comment: @NBN-Alex I agree with that, I have also succumbed to the "free wifi" connections. This can also happen when disconnecting from the wifi to switch to mobile data, if your coverage isn't amazing.

Comment: Thx guys. It works.

Comment: Hmmm ... Yesterday it was good when i tried it, but today again it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. In the settings, in the "datatraffic" the google services backgroung data using is disabled. (After install I disabled everything except Pokémon Go). After being enabled, it does not stuck at sign out phase. I hope it helps for you.

Comment: that why via wifi U can log in and via LTE you can't